# I wrote a guide for mythbuntu; how do I post it?

Tags: discussion

I'm a little confused; I don't really have a question, I just wanted to post a guide.  Do I ask a question that I'm providing the answer-for...or...??

Comment: Are you asking this for askubuntu? or for a wiki on www.ubuntu.com?

Comment: Askubuntu.  The MythBuntu forum recommends posting guides for it here.

Comment: You should ask a question, then answer it. There is even an option when asking to do this.

Comment: OK, I'll give that a try.

Comment: Wow, really hard to use.  Getting the formatting right take a long time.  I need 10 somethings to post more than two url's?  I already wrote this thing...now I need to re-write it?

Comment: I just spent the last hour trying to get the formatting correct, is there a simple way to put it in as just text?

Comment: Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You can answer 6/8/2014 11:39:49 PM. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead.

Comment: I'll just post it on the mythbuntu....  :(  forum.http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2228599

Comment: No, please do post it here! Those restrictions are hard sometimes, but we need them in place for various reasons (mostly spam and abuse). If you make 5 approved edits you will get 10 reputation, and most of the new user restrictions will be removed.

Comment: Just leave the links without the http:// on them, we'll fix them up.

Comment: The real issue was the formatting, I couldn't get to work.  Just when I thought the code blocks were OK, other stuff went south.  I pasted the text onto the MythBuntu forum as-is and it was fine.  I'll paste it here again...can you tell me what went wrong?  Here it is from the Mythbuntu forum:  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2228599

Comment: OK, maybe not.  I get this message when I try to ask a question: "You must have at least 5 reputation on Ask Ubuntu to ask a question."  Not sure what that means...

Comment: When you paste it into the question just mention it here, I can fix it for you.

Comment: The 5 reputation limit is just on meta. You should post the guide on the main site. http://askubuntu.com/. Just post it, we'll fix the formatting :-)

Comment: Any word on this? I'd like you to post it so you can get the reputation but if it's too hard I can just post it for you if you want!